# How to lock Windows 10 rotation in JavaFX8?(Microsoft Surface Pro)

Tags: windows, kotlin, javafx, rotation

I am using a surface pro and I want to lock the windows10 rotation or horizontally with CODE.
Please helpme.

like android code:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: There is no such feature in the JavaFX API.  You will most likely need to invoke a native window api to do that (for which I have no advice).

Comment: Would it be better to access the Windows registry and change the autorotate value? @jewelsea

Comment: You are probably right.  Perhaps investigate creating a native installation of the app using [jpackage](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392), that uses the wix toolset to create the installer and you could have the installer [set a registry key](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/write_a_registry_entry.html).  I don’t know what the key to lock the screen rotation is though, you would need to research to find one, if it exists.  You mention JavaFX 8, there is a native packager for that, but I recommend JavaFX 17 instead.